# What is the correct reference for the Note entity when using OData?

Tags: jquery, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

What is the correct reference for the Note entity when using OData?  I'm trying to use OData SDK.jquery.RetrieveRecord function to query the Note entity (schema name "Annotation") however I get error message "Error : 404: Not Found: Resource not found for the segment 'AnnotationSet'.

Here is the code I'm using.  productID is a GUID and "abpm_producto_Annotations" is the 1:N relationship.

```
SDK.JQuery.retrieveRecord(productID, "Annotation", "abpm_producto_Annotations", null, function (result) {
    if (result != null) {
        //A note is attached
    }
},
    errorHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that particular JavaScript SDK, but I'm assuming you are using this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309549.aspx#BKMK_SDKJQueryJS.

The retrieveRecord record looks up a record by its CRM ID, but it appears that you are looks like you are looking up a note (Annotation) by a product ID.

You likely want to construct the query using something similar to the following:

```
SDK.JQuery.retrieveRecord(productID, "Product", "abpm_producto_Annotations", null, function (result) {
if (result != null && result.abpm_producto_Annotations.length) {
    var firstNote = result.abpm_producto_Annotations[0];
}
```

},
    errorHandler);

You may want to use the ODATA Query Designer from the [Dynamics Xrm Tools](http://dynamicsxrmtools.codeplex.com/) product to make sure you have the correct relationship name.

Comment: Yes that is the library I'm using. I'm using SDK.JQuery.retrieveRecord to see if there are any related notes (not Product entity).

Comment: I confirmed with OData Query Designer (thanks!) that the entity set is indeed called "AnnotationSet".  So I'm a bit stuck here.

Comment: Did you understand my comment about your attempt at getting an annotation (note) by a product id?  What you want to do is retrieve the product, but select and expand the note relationship of the product.